# Does this organization still exist?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-infinity-war, thanos

In *Infinity War*, it is briefly mentioned that Thanos

> went to Xandar, destroyed half the population and took the Power Stone.

Do

> the Nova Corps

still exist? If so, in what capacity?

Comment: This will probably be revealed in future works.

Comment: @mooz That is a misuse of the future works policy. A question that may not yet have an answer is not synonymous with a question about a future work. It's very presumptuous to close a question about a released work just because you aren't aware of the answer to it.

Comment: Discussion on the closability of this question has been taken to [meta](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11853/31394).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am going to do my best to properly cover up spoilers but if you have not seen Infinity War and you don't want anything ruiined, **STOP READING NOW**

**The Actual Answer**

We don't know. It has not been addressed in any canon fashion yet.

**HOWEVER**

According to the [MCU Wiki](http://marvelcinematicuniverse.wikia.com/wiki/Nova_Corps) they were

> the **intergalactic** military and police force of the Nova Empire

AND we know they operate at least one [off world installation](http://marvelcinematicuniverse.wikia.com/wiki/Kyln)

These two points suggest that at least some of them were

> not on Xandar when Thanos attacked.

At this point, it bears mentioning that

> when he got his hands on all 6 Infinity Stones, Thanos was able to kill off half the life in the Universe at random. Prior to this, the exterminated half of the population of any planet he attacked would heavily favor the local military, police forces and anyone else who tried to stop the coming genocide-the rest would come from those rounded up after the fighting was over.

So assuming

> every member of the Nova Corps present on Xandar at the time of the attack fought Thanos and they fought to the last and did not surrender

The worst case scenario is that

> every member of the Nova Corps stationed on Xandar is dead but those off world could still be alive and operating in some reduced capacity.

Comment: You're perfectly fine to roll my edit back but I don't see how "the intergalactic military and police force of the Nova Empire" is a spoiler. I will however, edit out the disclaimer at the top of the answer, that is implicit for anyone reading the question.

Comment: Implicit doesn't mean people won't read. I'm keeping it. As for your other point, in keeping with the spirit of the original question I'm covering up any reference to which organization is being discussed

Comment: If they spoil Infinity War by reading a question on it, it is their own fault. As for keeping with the spirit generally questions have to be more careful than answers because to understand the answer you have to read the question. I disagree and think it makes your answer unnecessarily difficult to read but it's yours to do with as you please. I'm not going to get into an edit war over this.

Comment: The truth is, I wouldn't normally put the disclaimer in there. In this case, the movie has been out less than a week so I figure an additional layer of caution is justifiable (even if it is unnecessary).